# Recover multiple original files powershell due to onedrive sync issues

Tags: powershell, onedrive

We had a syncing issue that affected thousands of files.

A backup of the correct files was created in each folder by the sync tool. the backup has " -LocalPCName" added before the dot before the extension.

I am really a beginner in powershell.

I am trying to write a powershell script to go trough every folder and check if a file backup was create d for each file.

If a backup was created, I want to rename the file to add " -Wrongversion" and remove the " -LocalPCName" from the correct file.

This will basically recover the file to the correct version and make a copy of the wrong version.

I wrote this code but i am blocked at trying to match using -replace

```
Get-ChildItem *.* |
  ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.name -match "\s-LocalPCName")
     {Get-ChildItem $_.Name -replace "\s-LocalPCName","" 
             }
   }
```

Thank you for your help!

here is a newer version of my code but i get errors and i am concerned of using recurse, am i missing anything when this will go to subfolders? In this code, the LocalPCName is Didi2015

```
Get-ChildItem *.*  -recurse|
ForEach-Object {
If ($_.name -match "\s-Didi2015")
{

    $OldName = $_.Name -replace "\s-Didi2015","" 
    $dir=$_.DirectoryName
    $ext = $_.Extension
    $file = $OldName.Substring(0, $OldName.LastIndexOf('.'))

        Write-Output $dir
        Write-Output $ext
        Write-Output $file


    $Newname = $file + " -Wrongversion" + $ext
    Write-Output $Newname
    Rename-Item -Path $OldName -NewName $Newname -WhatIf

    Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $OldName -WhatIf

   }



}
```

Comment: I also tried with this code but nothing happens:  
  `Get-ChildItem -Filter “*-LocalPCName*” -Recurse | move-Item  -Destination ($_.name -replace "\s-LocalPCName","") -force `

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code. it works.

```
dir *-Didi2015*.* -Recurse|
ForEach-Object {
If ($_.name -match "-Didi2015")
    {

    $OldName = $_ -replace "-Didi2015","" 
    $dir=$_.DirectoryName
    $ext = $_.Extension
    $file = $OldName.Substring(0, $OldName.LastIndexOf('.'))

       # Write-Output $dir
       # Write-Output $ext
       # Write-Output $file
       # Write-Output $OldName
       # Write-Output $Newname
       # Write-Output $_.Name

    $Newname = $file + "-Wrongversion" + $ext
    Rename-Item -Path $OldName -NewName $Newname  -WhatIf 
    Rename-Item -Path $OldName -NewName $Newname  -Force 
    Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $OldName -WhatIf
    Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $OldName -Force

   }

}
```